# ajax chat own database how-to

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am using ajax chat from

[AJAX Chat](http://ajax-chat.sourceforge.net)

they have no database to register users and channels, instead they are manually inserted in lib/data/ folder. I want to create my own table for users and channels registration.

Can anyone help me out doing this, caz i cant find anything on internet. Available things are only integration with other forums. But i dont need any forum for this.

Thanks

Comment: you should read the related documentation thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the file and the registered user has the following parameters:

```
// Sample registered user:
$users[3] = array();
$users[3]['userRole'] = AJAX_CHAT_USER;
$users[3]['userName'] = 'user';
$users[3]['password'] = 'user';
$users[3]['channels'] = array(0,1);
```

So thats the fields you need to create in your MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `DATABSENAME`.`users` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userRole` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`userName` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
)
```

and

```
 CREATE TABLE `DATABSENAME`.`channels` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`channelname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
)
```

and

```
 CREATE TABLE `DATABSENAME`.`users_channels` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`number` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`userName` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
)
```

Then you have to load each user into your users.php something like:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

$j=4
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $users[$j]['userRole']=$row['userRole'];
  $users[$j]['userName']=$row['userName'];
  $users[$j]['password']=$row['password'];
  $j++;
  }


for($j=4;$j<(count($users)-4)$j++){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_channels WHERE userName='".$users[$j]['userName']."'");

$k=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     $k++;
     $user[$j]['channels'][$k]=$row['number'];
  } 
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Then you do practically the same for channels.php.
The second part involves making the database entries when a user registers, not sure how that works and which file that involves but if you know the application you should probably find it.